# Would a sniper bullet fired on Ceres reach orbital or even escape velocity?

Tags: orbit, physics, escape-velocity, ceres

What would happen if you fired a sniper bullet horizontally from the top of Ahuna Mons, the highest mountain of Ceres? Once I read somewhere that if you fired a bullet on the Moon in the correct angle, it could land on the other side of the Moon. If that's true, on Ceres with 0.00016 Earth masses and 0.029 the Earth's surface gravity a bullet surely could enter an orbit around Ceres if fired from Ahuna Mons, or even escape velocity if fired in the correct angle, or not?

Ceres' escape velocity is about 510 m/s (about 1670 ft/s). I think that's achievable by certain guns.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you fire horizontally. Escape velocity is independent of the angle, although of course you can't aim *below* horizontal.

Comment: To reach an orbit from the surface of Ceres using a firearm is impossible, The bullet would crash into the surface after one revolution. You need a sufficient height for a stable orbit due to the irregular shape of Ceres. For very low orbits you need a celestical body with a perfect spherical shape and symmetrical density.

Comment: @Uwe This is why I wrote "horizontally from the top of Ahuna Mons". Like this, it would achieve an orbit unless it reaches escape velocity. Ahuna Mons is a lonely mountain.

Comment: The lonely mountain is not high enough for a stable orbit. Ahuna Mons is only 5km. The Orbit of Dawn is between 35 and 400 km.

Comment: @Uwe What dya mean by "stable orbit"? Ceres has no atmosphere, only an exosphere. If you shoot from Ahuna Montis peak horizontally at the correct speed, the bullet will fall around Ceres and return to where it is shot from. Eventually the exosphere might let decay its orbit so that it crashes into the mountain, but the bullet would have achieved one.

Comment: Please read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_orbit#Perturbation_effects) about lunar mascons and their effect on low orbits. Moon is no perfect homogenous sphere, the same is true for Ceres.

Comment: @Uwe By shooting the bullet arbitrarily close to escape velocity, you can make the period arbitrarily long, the mean orbital height arbitrarily large, and the time spent in low orbit an arbitrarily small fraction of the period. Shooting from the ground only constitutes a "low orbit" if you fire with low enough velocity to have a circular orbit. Is an arbitrarily large orbit around a non-uniform body also inherently unstable?

Comment: Quite a few guns, not just sniper rifles, could hit the required velocity. Hell, even an FN P90 could do it (muzzle velocities are about 200 m/s higher than what's needed, and there's no air resistance to slow the bullet down), let alone most rifle cartridges and even some handguns (I'd actually be surprised if anything using a modern intermediate cartridge such as 5.56x45mm or 5.45x69mm couldn't do it, provided of course that it wasn't a subsonic load).

Comment: A search for "bullet ballistics chart" will provide the typical feet/s of many different cartridges.  Outside of an atmosphere, the actual velocity is likely to be much higher due to the lack of air resistance and air pressure in the barrel.  Here is one chart as an example: http://gundata.org/bullet-database/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, you are correct, it could reach escape velocity. The M110 can reach speeds of over 700 m/s, which is well above the escape velocity. Most guns actually don't need oxygen to work either, as the gun powder has the oxygen needed. So yeah, be extra careful where you fire a gun on an asteroid.

Comment: @uhoh There r many planetary moons you have to be careful on too: all Saturnian moons except Titan, all Uranian moons, Pluto's moon Charon and Eris' moon Dysnomia. Maybe you need to be careful on Europa too since it is less massive than the Moon and has a weaker surface gravity than the Moon. Probably _not_ on Triton, Eris or Pluto because they have considerable atmospheres.

Comment: Added the word "extra".

Comment: Obligatory "Men of Good Will" reference: https://books.google.com/books?id=nMp0CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT226&lpg=PT226&dq=men+of+good+will+ben+bova&source=bl&ots=5MOsBvMnux&sig=ACfU3U0T_bQikV3MBfDAZxDJ24iUiHRCdQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE_q7inbvqAhVRhq0KHfXnAIEQ6AEwBHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=men%20of%20good%20will%20ben%20bova&f=false

Comment: That's like Ford Prefect getting Earth's description changed to 'Mostly Harmless' @PearsonArtPhoto

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cannonball

Comment: @LoveForChrist Also, Endor. You might hit an Ewok.

Comment: @Acccumulation And Kashyyyk. You might hit a Wookie.

Comment: Even if most guns don't require oxygen, I'm betting that they jam in a vacuum. Super cold, and vacuum welding will cause the mechanical firing parts to fail.

Comment: Is there any gun that needs oxygen of the air?

Comment: @Uwe, there won't be any common gun that does.  Bullet casings are sealed enough that enough oxygen can't get in fast enough.  And even something like a muzzle loader, the chamber is still sealed enough to stop enough air from getting in.  And for what air leaks there are, all gas flow is out of the chamber once the ignition starts.

Comment: @GregMiller I was thinking the same. A gun requiring oxygen of the air is impossible. All fuel and oxidator needed for the explosion should be sealed within the chamber. An explosive gas mixture may be used instead of a solid explosive like gun powder.